# SET LOCK_TIMEOUT, is it session or statement based?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, locking, configuration

For what period does the `LOCK_TIMEOUT` last?

I do a `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 10` and a `SELECT @@LOCK_TIMEOUT` in one command after a login and get 10 returned. Immediately after this I do a `SELECT @@LOCK_TIMEOUT` again and it returns -1. I would have thought it still be 10.

I did some looking on the MSDN site and could not find if the `LOCK_TIMEOUT` is session based or statement based.

Comment: What I left out was doing a "SELECT @@spid" it returns 52 after both commands - indicating I am on the same connection - doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your application submit its queries via `sp_executesql`? (You can check this in Profiler if not sure)

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 10; 
                     SELECT @@LOCK_TIMEOUT';

SELECT @@LOCK_TIMEOUT;
```

Returns

```
-----------
10

-----------
-1
```

for me.

**Edit** And I also see the same kind of behaviour with `exec sp_prepexec`

```
declare @p1 int

exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,
                 NULL,
                 N'SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 10; SELECT @@LOCK_TIMEOUT AS LOCK_TIMEOUT_INSIDE' 

select @p1 AS handle, @@LOCK_TIMEOUT AS LOCK_TIMEOUT_OUTSIDE
```

Comment: From looking at the profiler - it does the following. declare 'at'p1 int
set 'at'p1=2
exec sp_prepexec 'at'p1 output,NULL,N'SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 10;
SELECT @@LOCK_TIMEOUT'
select 'at'p1

Comment: @DavidGrayWright - Looks like the same issue. Guess you'll need to see if you can get the application to stop using that for the call that sets the `LOCK_TIMEOUT` or explain a bit more about your situation to see if anyone can come up with another way of achieving the same result.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Is it that I can't call this stored procedure to make the change to **LOCK_TIMEOUT**? If so, why not? Why does the set _NOT_ impact outside the stored proc?

Comment: @DavidGrayWright - This runs as a child batch and when the child batch ends and the TSQL call stack unwinds the `SET` option gets restored to its previous value. See [the value of the SET option is restored after control is returned from the batch specified in the dynamic SQL string.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx)

Comment: I have the LOCK_TIMEOUT surviving past it's initial set point. I now use SQLExecDirect and bypass the stored procedure. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

From the [`SET LOCK_TIMEOUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189470.aspx) Books Online entry:

> "At the beginning of a connection, this setting has a value of -1.
>   After it is changed, the new setting stays in effect for the remainder
>   of the connection."

All the tests I have performed have reflected this documented behaviour.  Perhaps you are using different connections but getting the same session id?  Use this query to check:

```
SELECT 
    dec.connection_id, 
    dec.connect_time 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS dec 
WHERE 
    dec.session_id = @@SPID;
```

Comment: Yes, it all works fine in SSMS. I modified the application code to output the Connection Id as per your SQL statement above and I am getting two GUID's back... 7518881638be4b45a382cff71943798e and 16faaaa821497b42983e6eb08d4e74fe these are consistent. I have a method to reset the LOCK_TIMEOUT and to get the LOCK_TIMEOUT. The method that sets the LOCK_TIMEOUT also does a select so it returns 10. The method to get the LOCK_TIMEOUT is still returning -1.

Answer (score 2):

Although the SET LOCK_TIMEOUT documentation currently says it will stay in effect for the remainder of the connection, that is not entirely correct. It follows the same rules as other SET statements.

> If a SET statement is run in a stored procedure or trigger, the value of the SET option is restored after control is returned from the stored procedure or trigger. Also, if a SET statement is specified in a dynamic SQL string that is run by using either sp_executesql or EXECUTE, the value of the SET option is restored after control is returned from the batch specified in the dynamic SQL string.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql

Also, depending on how you are running the query, you may be using connection pooling. This can give you the same @@spid but does a `exec sp_reset_connection` when it retrieves a connection from the pool.