# Execute Stored Procedure with SET LOCK_TIMEOUT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, query-timeout

Is there anyway to execute stored procedure with `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT` explicitly?

E.g. I have sproc called `dbo.LoadData`. It just takes data from table `dbo.Abc` and insert them in table `dbo.Xyz`.

Now I want to execute the sproc `dbo.LoadData`, but if the table `dbo.Abc` is `locked` for e.g. more than 10 seconds, stop the execution of the stored procedure.

I know the option `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT` can be implemented in the sproc `dbo.LoadData` itself, but I am wondering if there is any way how to call it explicitly (= not implementing the option in the stored procedure itself).

Comment: any way how to call it explicitly--You mean at a session level?

Comment: Yes. Pseudocode: EXEC dbo.LoadData WITH SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 10.

Comment: Do yo mind explaining why you don't want to set it in the stored procedure itself?

Comment: Sure. There is one Master Stored procedure that starts other stored procedure based on some logic. So I want to move the LOCK TIMEOUT logic to this master stored proc and handle all the logic there.

Comment: It might be better to batch your inserts, then dial down the rows inserted until it finishes under your deadline.

Answer (score 3):

`LOCK_TIMEOUT` is not only a session-level setting, it also needs to be set in a separate batch. But, it cannot be set via a variable. So, this can be accomplished by using Dynamic SQL in the "master" Stored Procedure. This will allow for setting `LOCK_TIMEOUT` and then executing whatever other Stored Procedure that should run within this particular setting. It has to be a single execution of Dynamic SQL since the setting will revert back to the value of the top-most / outer-most process. For example:

Run this in one query tab in SSMS:

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE ##ShouldTimeout
AS
INSERT INTO ##LockedTable ([ID]) VALUES (1);
GO


GO
CREATE PROCEDURE ##TimeoutTest
(
    @SecondsUntilTimeout INT = 2
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @SecondsUntilTimeout = ISNULL(@SecondsUntilTimeout, 2); -- enforce default

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SET LOCK_TIMEOUT ';
SET @SQL += CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @SecondsUntilTimeout * 1000) + N';
';

SET @SQL += N'EXEC ##ShouldTimeout;'; -- use CASE / IF to decide what to exec

RAISERROR(@SQL, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT; -- print Dynamic SQL in "Messages" tab

EXEC (@SQL);
GO
```

Run the following in another query tab in SSMS:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
CREATE TABLE ##LockedTable (ID INT);

-- ROLLBACK
```

Now go back to the first query tab (where you created the two temporary Stored Procedures) and run the following two tests:

```
EXEC ##TimeoutTest;
-- this will timeout after 2 seconds (the default)


EXEC ##TimeoutTest 5;
-- this will timeout after 5 seconds
```

Now go back to the second query tab and execute the `ROLLBACK` ;-).

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that. This is a property of your connection.

Books online:

> At the beginning of a connection, this setting has a value of -1.
>   After it is changed, the new setting stays in effect for the remainder
>   of the connection. The setting of SET LOCK_TIMEOUT is set at execute
>   or run time and not at parse time.

Few example and discussion of how it can be used:

1. [SET LOCK_TIMEOUT, is it session or statement based?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11511/set-lock-timeout-is-it-session-or-statement-based)
2. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/01/28/sql-server-basic-explanation-of-set-lock_timeout-how-to-not-wait-on-locked-query/
3. [Can we set LOCK_TIMEOUT instance- or database-wide?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54826/can-we-set-lock-timeout-instance-or-database-wide)